# How to have table of contents?

Tags: chinese

Below is my script. I use WinEdt 10.3 and XeLatex to write Chinese. My question is (1) there is an output pdf file, but it does not pop up; (2) the output pdf file has no table of contents, even I use the commond `\tableofcontents`.

```
\documentclass[UTF8]{ctexbook}

\usepackage{bookmark}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{测试}
这是一个测试。
这是一个测试。
这是一个测试。
这是一个测试。
这是一个测试。
这是一个测试。
这是一个测试。
这是一个测试。
这是一个测试。

\chapter{测试}
这是第二个测试。
这是第二个测试。
这是第二个测试。
这是第二个测试。
这是第二个测试。
这是第二个测试。
这是第二个测试。
这是第二个测试。

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  If your file is filename.tex, you'll want to look through the file filename.log to see if something went wrong.  The table of contents gets loaded from the automatically created filename.toc.  Do those exist?  Does anything look wrong, as best you can tell?

Comment: Hi, @Teepeemm, thanks for your reply. I have the .toc file. This file says that: \contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {第一章\hspace {.3em}}测试1}{3}{chapter.1}%
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {第二章\hspace {.3em}}测试2}{5}{chapter.2}%

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which TeX distribution do you employ? (WinEdt is a front-end, not a TeX distribution.)

Answer (score 2):

You may have to compile twice to show the table of contents. The compliler generates `.toc` file the first time you compile, and until the second time, it adds `.toc` file to your output pdf.

If you have installed texlive, I suggest using

```
latexmk  -xelatex myfile.tex
```

to get table of contents in one run.